# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not go through

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I did

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
then sudo reboot.
```

When I tried to run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I go a strange message as follows
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

hy I say strange is because I dont have a dev environment if I am not mistaken, here is the outcome of lsb_release

> LSB
> Version:  core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Release: 18.04
> Codename: bionic

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Direct upgrade is usually available only after the first point release (20.04.1). To force it you need to use the special options of the command.

> -d – this allows us to upgrade to 20.04; normally, this option is used by early testers to try development versions of Ubuntu ahead of their official release. We will use it to start the upgrade. While the labels say “development”, don’t worry – we will in fact be upgrading to the stable, official release of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
> -f – this option will launch a graphical guided wizard. Without it, the do-release-upgrade tool will run in the command-line. The process is otherwise identical.

I hope you are prepared for possible mishaps, you can never know.

Comment: OK I will use the -d key and let you know, thanks

Comment: I will use the button Answer you question as my response is longer than 300

Answer (score 0):

Something very strange happened, after issuing `do-release-upgrade`, I had a black screen with a blinking dash for almost 24 hours. (when trying to connect through Hyper-V directly), then I tried to RDP, It was successful but all links on the desktop were not recognized and I had a red X on them I opened a terminal and checked `lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Then I ran

```
$ sudo apt update                                                                                   1514 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I did again `sudo apt upgrade`, surprisingly I got

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 grub-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
               Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
                Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
 initramfs-tools-core : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (= 0.136ubuntu6.2) but 0.130ubuntu3.9 is installed
.......
........
..
```

the list was very long. I did

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After a while, my icons and links came back to live.

Comment: I issued again apt upgrade and started to upgrade 1G of packages again

Comment: It continued working, all of a sudden, screen disappeared waited for 1 hour then restarted the VM and I was able to log with RDP, I will make the story short, now when I run sudo apt upate I get  30 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: run sudo apt upgrade, I get 
Reading package.. Done
Building ..
Reading state information..
Calculating upgrade..
The following packages been kept back
  colord evolution-data-server fwupdate gcc-8-base gcc-8-base:i386 gvfs
  gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs
  libebackend-1.2-10 libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri libmpx2
  libsane-common libsane1 libsmbclient libwbclient0 lm-sensors orage orca
  python-psutil samba-libs sane-utils xfce4-mailwatch-plugin
  xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-panel
0 upg, 0 newly inst, 0 to remove 30 not upgraded.